# editing "special price" from frontend is saving in "Price" field in Backend

Tags: magento-1.9, price, controllers, special-price, multi-vendor

we are having marketplace [multi vendor] site. so in each seller or vendor account we are displaying name, sku, price .... etc.
so that sellers/vendors can edit the product information and save . so it will reflect in backend....
we are using following code to display "Price". in the same way i want to display special Price also. for that what i am trying is in following code
a) In Php code I am replacing `<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>`  by
`<?php echo $products->getSpecialPrice(); ?>` but

its not saving in backend. please give what changes i need to do in below code to work for special price.  This is code for Price.

**Php**

```
<span id="valueprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>">
<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?></span> 



    <input type = "text" id = "price_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" "name = "price" value = "<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>" style = "display:none"/>


        <!-- aki 2 -->
    <span class="label wk_action" id="edit_link_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>">
<img onclick="showFieldPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/icon-edit.png'); ?>"/>
</span>  
<p id="updatedprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red;">Updated</p>
                <br/>
<button id="price_update_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" class="button wk_mp_btn1" onclick="updateFieldPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" style="display:none" >
<span><span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span></span>
    </button>
    <button id="price_reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideResetPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" style="display:none" >
<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
        </button>                                                       
    </span>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script>
function showFieldPrice(product_id)
        {
            /*
            var qtyId = '#qty_'+ product_id;

            var editLink = "#edit_link_"+ product_id;
            var updateButton = "#update_button_"+ product_id;
            var resetButton = "#reset_button"+ product_id;

            $wk_jq(qtyId).toggle()

            $wk_jq(editLink).hide();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).show();
            $wk_jq(resetButton).show();

            $qty = $wk_jq(qtyId).val();
            */          
            var qtyId='#price_'+ product_id;

            var editLink="#price_edit_link_"+ product_id;
            var updateButton="#price_update_button_"+ product_id;
            var resetButton="#price_reset_button_"+ product_id;

            $wk_jq(qtyId).show();

            $wk_jq(editLink).hide();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).show();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).prop('disabled', false);//just in case
            $wk_jq(resetButton).show();

            return false;


        }
        </script>
```

**controller.php**

```
public function updateFieldPriceAction(){
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);      
        $id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $collection_product = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$id))->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$customerid));
        //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setEditProductId($id);

        try{
        $upd_price = $this->getRequest()->getParam('special_price');
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);        
        //$product->setData('price', $upd_price);
        $product->setPrice($upd_price);

        //$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($id);
        //$stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 1);
        //$stockItem->setData('qty', $this->getRequest()->getParam('qty'));
        $product->save();

        echo $price = $product->getPrice();
        echo $name = $product->getName();

        $response['message'] = 'Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated';
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response)); 
        //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated'));


        //endif;
        }catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Not Saving"; exit;    
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        }

      }
  }
```

for special price i am using following code :

**PHP**

```
<span class="label pro_status">
    <?php //echo $products->getSpecialPrice(); ?>

    <span id="valueprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>">
    <?php echo $products->getSpecialPrice(); ?></span> 



    <input type = "text" id = "price_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" "name = "price" value = "<?php echo $products->getSpecialPrice(); ?>" style = "display:none"/>





    <span class="label wk_action" id="edit_link_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>">
            <img onclick="showFieldPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/icon-edit.png'); ?>"/>
                </span>  
            <p id="updatedprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red;">Updated</p>
            <br/>
            <button id="price_update_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" class="button wk_mp_btn1" onclick="updateFieldSpecialPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" style="display:none" >
            <span><span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span></span>
                </button>
            <button id="price_reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideResetPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" style="display:none" >
            <span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
            </button>                                                       
            </span>
```

JS

```
<script>
function updateFieldSpecialPrice(product_id)
        {
            var priceId = '#price_'+ product_id;
            var valueId = '#valueprice_'+ product_id;
            var updatedqty = '#updatedprice_'+ product_id;


            var editLink = "#price_edit_link_"+ product_id;
            var updateButton = "#price_update_button_"+ product_id;
            var resetButton = "#price_reset_button"+ product_id;
            var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateFieldSpecialPrice/')?>';

            $wk_jq(priceId).toggle()

            $wk_jq(editLink).hide();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).hide();
            $wk_jq(resetButton).hide();

            $price = $wk_jq(priceId).val();
            jQuery(valueId).html($price);
            hideReset(product_id);

            new Ajax.Request(url, {
                method: 'post',
                parameters: {id: product_id, price: $price},
                onComplete: function (transport) {
                    //alert(transport.responseText);

                    jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut();

                    $updateButton.prop('disabled', false);

                    $wk_jq(priceId).setValue($price);



                }
            });
        }

</script>
```

**controllers**

```
public function updateFieldSpecialPriceAction(){
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);      
        $id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $collection_product = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$id))->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$customerid));
        //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setEditProductId($id);

        try{
        $upd_price = $this->getRequest()->getParam('price');
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);        
        //$product->setData('price', $upd_price);
        $product->setSpecialPrice($upd_price);

        //$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($id);
        //$stockItem->setData('manage_stock', 1);
        //$stockItem->setData('qty', $this->getRequest()->getParam('qty'));
        $product->save();

        echo $price = $product->getPrice();
        echo $name = $product->getName();

        $response['message'] = 'Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated';
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response)); 
        //Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated'));


        //endif;
        }catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Not Saving"; exit;    
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        }

      }
```

Comment: replace `$product->setPrice($upd_price);`  with 
`$product->setSpecialPrice($upd_price);`   in controllers

Comment: please check updated question

Comment: please tell me what and all chnages  i have to do in php, javascript and contrololers code, because special prices column in frontend is empty.

Comment: where you change it i said add in your controller function

Comment: i chnaged in controllers file, i edited in seller account .....now its giving blank in backend

Comment: i eidted the special price from seller account, once i edited its displaying price in seller account 

and special price is showing empty in backend

Comment: this thing are not handled by ext?

Comment: no, this is not from extension, From above code in the question, "Price" is working fine.

Comment: `$product->setSpecialPrice($upd_price);
$product->setSpecialFromDate('');
$product->setSpecialFromDateIsFormated(false);

$product->setSpecialToDate('');
$product->setSpecialToDateIsFormated(false);`   add this whole code for updating the special price..

Comment: same result, once seller edit the special price, special price field become empty in backend.

Comment: what special price is displaying in backend , its reflecting in seller account.

but once seller edit the special price from his account, than its not saving in backend. instead

special price field in backend is empty

Comment: i changed from $product->setSpecialPrice($upd_price);  to $product->setFinalPrice($upd_price); 

now only problem is its not saving backend. but special price is not becoming blank. but old value only reflecting in the backend

Comment: finalprice is something else so don't change it and it will not show anywhere..

Comment: okay, i reverted back the changes......

Comment: sorry, i put getFinalPrice in php code instead of getSppecial Price . now special price is working fine. but if seller click on edit button in "special Price" column, than "Price button is allowing to edit. please help what code i need to use to work for both price and special price at once.

Comment: if working then it good because it will show the special price it has else show the price.

Comment: ya, if i use only special price than its works fine, if i use only price than alos its works fine , if i add both code, problems are appearing , means if seller click on edit button in "special Price" column, than "Price button is allowing to edit. please edit the question with both the code to work.....

Comment: you are getting the price to display so you have to edit the price..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31782/discussion-between-baby-in-magento-2-and-qaisar-satti).

Comment: for this question you gave me an answer, please post your comment as answer. but i did't got an answer here :

http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/91239/trying-to-edit-special-price-but-its-allowing-to-edit-price

Comment: done on both question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace `$product->setPrice($upd_price);` with `$product->setSpecialPrice($upd_price);` in controllers