# Trying to edit special price but its allowing to edit price

Tags: magento-1.9, php, javascript, ajax

we are having marketplace [multi vendor] site. so in each seller/vendor account we are displaying name, sku, price .... etc. so that sellers/vendors can edit the product information and save . so it will reflect in backend.... we are using following code to display "Price" and "special price". if we click edit button on "special Price field" , its allowing to edit "Price Field". Please help me what code i need to add to fix this . I am trying following code :

**Php code for Price**

```
<span id="valueprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>">
<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?></span> 



    <input type = "text" id = "price_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" "name = "price" value = "<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>" />



    <span class="label wk_action" id="edit_link_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>">
<img onclick="showFieldPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/icon-edit.png'); ?>"/>
</span>  
<p id="updatedprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red;">Updated</p>
                <br/>
<button id="price_update_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" class="button wk_mp_btn1" onclick="updateFieldPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" style="display:none" >
<span><span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span></span>
    </button>
    <button id="price_reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideResetPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" style="display:none" >
<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
        </button>                                                       
    </span>
```

**php code for special price**

```
    <span id="valueprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>"><?php echo $products->getSpecialPrice(); ?></span>
<input type = "text" id = "price_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" "name = "price" value = "<?php echo $products->getSpecialPrice(); ?>" style = "display:none"/>



<span class="label wk_action" id="edit_link_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>">
<img onclick="showFieldPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/icon-edit.png'); ?>"/>
</span>  
<p id="updatedprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red;">Updated</p>
    <br/>
<button id="price_update_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" class="button wk_mp_btn1" onclick="updateFieldPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" style="display:none" >
<span><span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span></span>
</button>
<button id="price_reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideResetPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" style="display:none" >
<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
</button>
```

**Javascript and ajax code for price**

```
<script>

function updateFieldPrice(product_id)
        {
            var priceId = '#price_'+ product_id;
            var valueId = '#valueprice_'+ product_id;
            var updatedqty = '#updatedprice_'+ product_id;


            var editLink = "#price_edit_link_"+ product_id;
            var updateButton = "#price_update_button_"+ product_id;
            var resetButton = "#price_reset_button"+ product_id;
            var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateFieldPrice/')?>';

            $wk_jq(priceId).toggle()

            $wk_jq(editLink).hide();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).show();
            $wk_jq(resetButton).show();

            $price = $wk_jq(priceId).val();
            jQuery(valueId).html($price);
            hideReset(product_id);

            new Ajax.Request(url, {
                method: 'post',
                parameters: {id: product_id, price: $price},
                onComplete: function (transport) {
                    //alert(transport.responseText);

                    jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut();

                    $updateButton.prop('disabled', false);

                    $wk_jq(priceId).setValue($price);



                }
            });
        }
        function updateAllFields(product_id) {
            updateFieldPrice(product_id);
            updateField(product_id);
            }
    </script>
```

**Javascript and ajax code for special price**

```
function updateFieldSpecialPrice(product_id)
        {
            var priceId = '#price_'+ product_id;
            var valueId = '#valueprice_'+ product_id;
            var updatedqty = '#updatedprice_'+ product_id;


            var editLink = "#price_edit_link_"+ product_id;
            var updateButton = "#price_update_button_"+ product_id;
            var resetButton = "#price_reset_button"+ product_id;
            var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateFieldPrice/')?>';

            $wk_jq(priceId).toggle()

            $wk_jq(editLink).hide();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).show();
            $wk_jq(resetButton).show();

            $price = $wk_jq(priceId).val();
            jQuery(valueId).html($price);
            hideReset(product_id);

            new Ajax.Request(url, {
                method: 'post',
                parameters: {id: product_id, price: $price},
                onComplete: function (transport) {
                    //alert(transport.responseText);

                    jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut();

                    $updateButton.prop('disabled', false);

                    $wk_jq(priceId).setValue($price);



                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this whole code for updating the special price.

```
$product->setSpecialPrice($upd_price);
 $product->setSpecialFromDate(''); 
$product->setSpecialFromDateIsFormated(false); 
$product->setSpecialToDate(''); 

$product->setSpecialToDateIsFormated(false);
```

Comment: still same error....

Comment: in office working bro see it later got free time sorry for that